# React Native fontWeight: 'bold', only shows in Android for TextInput

Tags: react-native

I have a `TextInput` with this style:

```
  title: {
    fontSize: TITLE_SECONDARY,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: COLOR_DARK_PRIMARY,
  },
```

However, the text only appears to be `'bold'` on Android but remains to be a regular font in iOS, as shown below ("Company Name" section):

[image]

I have also used element inspector to debug and indeed TextInput has `fontSize: TITLE_SECONDARY,` property in iOS.

The code for TextInput is as below:

```
    <TextInput
      style={[styles.title, styles.extraMargin]}
      value={this.state.company}
      underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent'
      onChangeText={(company) => this.setState({company})}
      placeholder="Company Name"
    />
```